# How to use JSON properties as axis tick values in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to use the following JSON properties as x axis values in D3? The intension would be a bar for each year property along x axis, and the value of each year property to be the y axis.

**data.json**

```
{
    "2008": 63,
    "2011": 28,
    "2014": 88,
    "2017": 55,
    "2018": 15,
    "2018": 23,
    "2020": 82
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In d3.js you specify the axis values by the domain of the [scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale). The domain of a scale is an array with two elements, the start value and the end value.

My example below starts with converting your data into the data format typically used in most d3.js examples with

```
  const data = Object.keys(json_data).map(d => ({"year": new Date(d), "value": +json_data[d]}));
```

You obtain the following data:

```
[
  {"year": 2008-01-01, "value": 63},
  {"year": 2011-01-01, "value": 28},
  {"year": 2014-01-01, "value": 88},
  {"year": 2017-01-01, "value": 55},
  {"year": 2018-01-01, "value": 23},
  {"year": 2020-01-01, "value": 82},
]
```

Then you can follow the standard d3 examples out there, e.g.:

```js
  
  const json_data = {
    "2008": 63,
    "2011": 28,
    "2014": 88,
    "2017": 55,
    "2018": 15,
    "2018": 23,
    "2020": 82,
  };
  const data = Object.keys(json_data).map(d => ({"year": new Date(d), "value": +json_data[d]}));

  const margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};
  const width = 800;
  const height = 600;
  
  const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

  const x = d3.scaleUtc()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.year))       
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])  

  const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])      
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]); // start from the bottom and go to the top

  const line = d3.line()
    .x(d => x(d.year))
    .y(d => y(d.value));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x)); 
  
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
  
  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("d", line);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```